# String formatting - combine multiple forms

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I've read the docs about string formatting [mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), and found out about few cool features:

integer representations:

```
'{0:X}'.format(16) # output is '10'
```

padding with zeros:

```
'{0:03X}'.format(16) # output is '010'
```

and alternate forms:

```
'{0:#X}'.format(16) # output is '0X10'
```

My question - is there a way combining all 3 in single command?
For instance:

```
'{0:#03X}'.format(16) # output is '0x10', desired output is '0x010'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify some more digits:

```
print('{0:#05x}'.format(16))
```

Output:

```
0x010
```

You need 5 and not 3 because `0x` are also considered when padding the output.

---

Beside that, you can always *hack* your output usign string concattenation or [`zfill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
print('0x'+'{0:03x}'.format(16) )
print('0x'+ '{:x}'.format(16).zfill(3))
```

Comment: Thanks! did not take this into consideration :)

Comment: Fully agree on the zfil comment, though I was hoping there was a neater way formatting :)